Correct way to implement interface in Golang for UnitTesting an SDK
I am trying to UnitTest my Go code that uses AWS SDK V2.
main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
)

type ClientInterface interface {
    DescribeLaunchTemplates(ctx context.Context, params *ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesInput, optFns ...func(*ec2.Options)) (*ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesOutput, error)
}

func CheckIfTemplateExists(client ClientInterface) (bool, error) {
    fmt.Println("CheckIfTemplateExists got called")
    template, err := client.DescribeLaunchTemplates(context.TODO(), &ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesInput{
        LaunchTemplateNames: []string{"AppOne"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in CheckIfTemplateExists")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return false, err
    }
    fmt.Println("Received a return in CheckIfTemplateExists")
    for _, lt := range template.LaunchTemplates {
        fmt.Println("No Error in CheckIfTemplateExists")
        fmt.Println(*lt.DefaultVersionNumber)
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}

func main() {

    defaultConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    svc := ec2.NewFromConfig(defaultConfig)

    CheckIfTemplateExists(svc)

}



main_test.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
)

type MockEC2LTClient struct {
    Client *ec2.Client
}

func (m *MockEC2LTClient) DescribeLaunchTemplates(ctx context.Context, params *ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesInput, optFns ...func(*ec2.Options)) (*ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesOutput, error) {
    fmt.Println("This should get called")
    return &ec2.DescribeLaunchTemplatesOutput{}, nil
}

func TestCheckifTemplateExists(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("CheckIfTemplateExists", func(t *testing.T) {
        defaultConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        svc := ec2.NewFromConfig(defaultConfig)

        m := &MockEC2LTClient{
            Client: svc,
        }

        CheckIfTemplateExists(m)
    })
}

This works.
I just want to confirm if this is the right way to do it?
Is there a better way to achieve this?

I think your question is too broad. Why are you in doubt? Personally, I would not make MockEC2LTClient a pointer receiver, but it's not wrong. Also, a line like var _ ClientInterface = (*MockEC2LTClient)(nil) helps you to ensure you're implementing the interface correctly (and often enables some IDE support), but for this testing use-case it's not really necessary either.

I think it should create set of interfaces to generate mock for unit test
I changed your source code a little bit, I just do mockable your interface. In case that you want to test AWS interface (ec2.go), please take a look: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ec2/ec2iface/
I hope this will be help
ec2.go
// mockgen -destination=mocks/mock_ec2.go -package=mocks github.com/your-username/your-repo-name/ec2 AwsEC2Instance

// ec2Client is a wrapper around the AWS EC2 client
type ec2Client struct {
    ec2Client *ec2.EC2
}

type AwsEC2Instance interface {
    // define your interface here
    DescribeInstances() error
}

func NewEC2Client() (*ec2Client, error) {
    // Load the SDK's config from environment and shared config
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &ec2Client{
        ec2Client: ec2.NewFromConfig(cfg),
    }, nil
}

func (e *ec2Client) DescribeInstances() error {
    return nil
}

main.go
func main() {
    ec2Client, err := NewEC2Client()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating EC2 client", err)
        return
    }

    err = ec2Client.DescribeInstances()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error describing EC2 instances", err)
        return
    }
}

main_test.go
func TestMain (t *testing.T) {
    // mock the EC2 client
    // call the function to be tested
    // assert the result
    mockedEC2Client := &mocks.AwsEC2Instance{}
    err := mockedEC2Client.DescribeInstances()
}


this is for AWS sdk v1. I am specifically interested in the AWS SDK V2

you're right, iface only supports for v1.
In case you want do unit test for aws interface implementation, your code is good. my code is just example of  interface-based and mockable
